# Convert a 2 bytes char array to int

Tags: c

I was confused on how to get this code working:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char xx[]={1,3};

    int xxx=*((int*)xx);
    printf("val is %d\r\n",xxx);
}
```

Will the code print 13 or 31? When I tried it, it prints out a big number, not what I was expecting.

Comment: If on your system, int is not 16 bit, you are reading past the end of the array. That is undefined behaviour, because you also read any garbage that is stored there. But even if you had used a 16 bit integer type, you would still depend on the endianness of the platform. But whatever the endianness, the output would not be 31 or 13, unless you had 4-bit bytes. <g>.

Comment: 1 is SOH (start of heading), 3 is ETX (end of text). Did you mean '1' and '3' instead?

Comment: You already self-answered the only question asked in your post. Your program printed *neither* 13 nor 31, as you noted.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ? It won't print 13 nor 31 even if  `int` is 16 bits on your platform.

Comment: isn't it like `(int*)xx` violates strict aliasing?

Comment: @SouravGhosh AFAIK, it's the dereferencing that breaks strict aliasing. The cast itself is possible UB for a different reason: `&xx` might not be suitably aligned.

Comment: @SouravGhosh guess so too

Answer (score 3):

I am not really sure what is your goal but you may want to use something like

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char xx[]= "13";
    printf("val is %s\r\n",xx);
}
```

or

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char xx[]={1,3};
    int xxx = xx[0] * 10 + xx[1];
    printf("val is %d\r\n",xxx);
}
```

Comment: If you don't understand the question, why do you post an answer?

Comment: I am not sure is not the same as I am not able to understand anything - if the guess is wrong I will delete the answer

Comment: @Ingo These are the two most likely expected ways the code should behave. One is simply about printing digits 1 and 3 as contents of a char array, the other includes parsing to int and then printing out the result. Both match the expected result. That the OP is confused about the meaning of `1` and `'1'` as `char` initializers doesn't make his question that unclear imo.

Comment: @TinyT Yeah, maybe in your opinion it isn't unclear. Maybe in mine it isn't either. But this answer starts with saying that the author doesn't understand the question. If they don't understand it, they shouldn't answer it. Imho.

Comment: Again - I did not say I do not understand it but I am not sure if my understanding of it is correct. Maybe you do not understand the introduction of the answer

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that you have `sizeof(int)` as 4. The int `xxx` has 2 bytes filled, but the other two bytes are random. That is why you are getting a big number.

If you change it to

```
 unsigned char xx[]={1,3,0,0};
```

then, on a little-endian machine you will get an output of `769'

This is because in a little endian system, the LSByte is stored first (0x01) then the next most significant byte (0x02) and then the other bytes (0x00, 0x00)

The number `xxx` becomes `0x00000301` or `769`

On a big endian machine (Power PC, or certain microcontrollers) the MSbyte is stored first. So `xxx` becomes `0x01030000` or `16973824`